# Does showAll change stageWidth on embedded content?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I've got a MovieClip that gets positioned in respect of the stage.stageWidth/stage.stageHeight which works completely fine in the stand-alone Flash Player, however when embedded into a webpage with the "showAll" param it gets cropped.

Is anyone aware of  some sort of issue with stageWidth not being updated when using the scale param in the embed code?

Comment: what's your wmode value?

Comment: I'm 80% sure that the `stageWidth` doesn't change except when you use `StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE`, but I haven't tested it.

Comment: Hi Anon, I would have thought the reverse - noscale would def not change the stageWidth.. But as for showAll yeah not sure hence the question

Answer (score 1):

`scale` - Possible values: showall, noborder, exactfit, noscale. Specifies how Flash Player scales SWF content to fit the pixel area specified by the OBJECT or EMBED tag.

1. `default` (Show all) makes the entire SWF file visible in the specified area without distortion, while maintaining the original aspect ratio of the movie. Borders can appear on two sides of the movie.
2. `noborder` scales the SWF file to fill the specified area, while
   maintaining the original aspect ratio of the file. Flash Player can
   crop the content, but no distortion occurs.
3. `exactfit` makes the entire SWF file visible in the specified area
   without trying to preserve the original aspect ratio. Distortion can
   occur.
4. `noscale` prevents the SWF file from scaling to fit the area of the
   OBJECT or EMBED tag. Cropping can occur.

Segment taken from [this page](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html).

This is basically saying that the scale attribute will determine how the content scales within the flash player. So, the ONLY mode that will change the stage width/height values is "noscale". In this mode, the pixel area and stage will always be a 1:1 ratio.

Comment: Hi Corey, I've been doing some more testing and I think the cause might actually be when I reference the MC width as its using the "unscaled" width of the MC as opposed to the scaled width, anyway still investigating